# Core Dump when deleting pointer C++

Tags: c++, pointers, coredump

I am learning C++ and here I am trying to implement the pop() function of a stack.  I am confused about when to delete pointers, and how to delete them correctly.  The following code causes a core dump error, however I found a few ways to avoid the core dump.  The problem is that I point a pointer to another pointer, and I want to delete both.  If I set one to null I can delete both, but if I point one to the other I cannot delete both.  What is the appropriate course of action here and why can't I delete both when one points to the other?  Also, this is not a doubly linked list, and I am not keeping track of the second node from the top so I must traverse the entire list to delete from the top.

I apologize as it seems that this question gets asked often.  There are so many discussions that I cannot sort out one that addresses my problem specifically.

```
int List::pop() {
    int result = -1;
    if (head != NULL) {
        result = curr->data;
        nodePtr delPtr;
        if (curr == head) {
            delPtr = head;
            head = NULL;
        }
        else {
            nodePtr previousNode = head;
            while(previousNode->next != curr) {
                previousNode = previousNode->next;
            }
            delPtr = curr;
            curr = previousNode;
            curr->next = NULL;
            previousNode = delPtr;   //previousNode = NULL;?????
            delete previousNode;     //unecessary?????
        }
    delete delPtr;    //Have to delete this one no matter what
    }
    else {
        cout << "The stack is empty" << endl;
    }
    return result;
}//END pop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are deleting the `curr` node twice.

Once in these lines:

```
previousNode = delPtr;   //previousNode = NULL;?????
delete previousNode;     //unecessary?????
```

and once in the line:

```
delete delPtr;    //Have to delete this one no matter what
```

You can remove the first two lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove both these lines:

```
 previousNode = delPtr;   //previousNode = NULL;?????
 delete previousNode;     //unecessary?????
```

And it will work and be correct.

The error is from deleting the same pointer twice.
`previousNode =  delPtr` is just making a copy of the pointer, there is still only one object.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `delete` twice, you are only removing one item.

Just because a pointer points to something **doesn't** mean you have to `delete` it if you change the pointer or it goes out of scope.

In general, you need to match up `delete`s with `new`s.

In short, you can remove both your commented lines as you already have `delPtr` set up for deleting.

Answer (score 0):

```
int List::pop() 
{
    int result = -1;
    if (head != NULL) 
    {
        nodePtr prev = head;
        nodePtr curr = head;

        while (curr->next != NULL)
        {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }

        result = curr->data;
        if (head == curr) 
        {
            head = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            prev->next = NULL;
        }

        delete curr;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "The stack is empty" << endl;
    }
    return result;
}//END pop
```